# I'm having a problem with the stuff in my Godot mobile game

Tags: godot, gltf, opengl-es-3.0, mipmaps, godot3

I exported a 3d model with materials from blender to the format in *.glb(binary). I will import this file into Godot and then inherit the scene. In my project, I put the Clear Color mode in the background, and set the ambient color to black. I install a camera next to my object and direct the light at the object. I run it on my PC and all the materials are displayed normally, but when I run it on android, the materials turn black. It only helps to remove the check mark from mipmaps, but this is not a solution, as performance drops. I have Godot 3.5. How to make mipmaps display correctly on mobile phones when importing from glb.

Comment: I figured out the problem a bit. In the material, the texture by default rises in an ImageTexture format, but if it is replaced with an image of the Texture format, it will work well.

Comment: A few things to try: gltf instead of glb, or if it is not too much trouble for your workflow, saving the glb as a Godot scene (save as...). You could also try switching between  GLES2 and GLES3.

Comment: Switched to GLES2, it worked. But I don't really like it, GLES 3 is a newer version and why doesn't it work with mipmaps? Although if the same image is re-imported as Texture and applied to this material, then everything works fine in GLES3

Comment: Godot 3 GLES3 implementation was built for features, not for compatibility. So it expects some GL extensions without fallback, so when it runs in an environment that does not support such extensions (which is somewhat common in smartphones) you get black.

Comment: I found a solution. Before importing to glb, you need to export the image to 16 bits per channel rgba